# Remove index.php from url YII

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I am new to yii and facing some issues with the url. I don't want `index.php` in my url. I've tried following code:

**`.htaccess` file:**

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I have added following in my `main.php` file:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',

            'caseSensitive'=>false,        
            ),
```

if i remove index.php manually it is ok . bt if i click on menu link it goes to

```
<div id="mainmenu">
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('post/index')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('site/contact')),
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely you have not set Apache config correctly

to turn on Rewrite Condition by changing AllowOveride directive in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (location may be different depending on OS , you can of course also turn it only for application directory only)

```
<Directory>
...
        AllowOverride None
....
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory>
...
        AllowOverride All
....
</Directory>
```

for enabling rewrite module you can do ( may vary depending on OS)

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache2 after

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i have changed the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All..no effect

Comment: restarted server ? is rewrite module enabled?, when you query a controller without index.php what is the error/message you are getting?, if blank check apache error log for stack trace and add the output

Comment: I have restarted the module and also rewrite module is enabled  bt when i remove index.php it is running correctly . but if i click on menu bar it is going to the url with index.php  . my menu code is given

Comment: <div id="mainmenu">
  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
   'items'=>array(
    array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('post/index')),
    array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
    array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('site/contact')),
    array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
    array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
   ),
  )); ?>

Comment: You seem to be using Yii routing for generating the routing logic, perhaps you didn't refresh the page after restarting the browser?, the old logic might have been generated previous to URL change.

Comment: where is yii routing file ?  actually i am new to yii.

Comment: there is no seperate routing file; i meant using Normalized Url http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#normalizeUrl-detail, if refresh does not work, try clearing you cache and see if the urls are generated correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is for ,please uncomment it first

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Check here for more info yii http://thewayofcoding.com/2009/11/clean-urls-in-php-yii-framework/